# How can I find people interested in selling BTC through Ripple?

Tags: ripple

I would like to buy bitcoins and I'm curious where I can find people who would want to sell me bitcoins through ripple platform.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a meeting place.

Comment: No SE "is not a meeting place", but the answer is basically that Ripple has an internal distributed exchange so no "finding people" is required, just entering/taking/viewing trade offers.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the most active USD/BTC order book on Ripple is for Bitstamp USD to Bitstamp BTC.

Add a contact to your wallet called `Bitstamp`, account `rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B`. (You should [double check this](https://bitstamp.net/ripple.txt), someone could edit this answer to try to steal your money.)

Then, on the trade page, select `BTC/USD`. Just to the right of that, for both issuers, enter `Bitstamp`.